# C# algorithm for N-gram

Tags: c#, text-mining, information-retrieval, n-gram

I am intending to use the n-gram code from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tfidf.aspx). The algorithm produces these tri-gram results:

```
t, th, the, he, e, q, qu, qui, uic, ick, ck, k, r, re, red, ed, d
```

for the text `the quick red`

However [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram#Examples), reckons it should be:

```
the  qui  k_r
he_  uic  _re
e_q  ick  red
_qu  ck_
```

(space indicated by ‘_’).

What is correct? Are there any other C# implementation out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example is correct.

ps. Why do you generate trigrams for the complete text and not only for words? What is your use case?

Comment: I believe this is useful for 'words' which actually consist of two strings (i.e. are separated by a space). This would be lost if a apply a word breaker first.

Answer (score 2):

The first is correct. I uses character N-gram on my thesis. You must move forward and pass one character for each step. In this condition, similar words can be found.